# Linking together TextChanged and SelectionChanged for a WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a situation where I would like to cause the text entered into an editable ComboBox become selected whenever it is altered and the TextChanged handler is called.  The reason being that some very important work is done inside the combobox's SelectionChanged handler.

The ComboBox is defined in code behind like this:

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="callListView" AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets" >
               <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=extensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  Width="105" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Key, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="chooseExtension_SelectionChanged"
                                  TextBoxBase.TextChanged="chooseExtension_TextChanged" IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
                           <ComboBox.Resources>
                              <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>
                           </ComboBox.Resources>
                        </ComboBox>
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
<!-- a bunch of unrelated stuff was removed to keep this simple -->
         </ListView.View>
```

Is there some way to make the current text after the TextChanged become the ComboBox's SelectedValue?